# Quickblox - How can I push notification to both platform Android and iOS?

Tags: android, push-notification, quickblox

QBEvent is class that Quickblox provides to support push notification.
On Android platform, I must set `qbEvent.setPushType(QBPushType.GCM)` to push message between multiple Android devices.

The problem is I want to push message for both Android and iOS, but I can set those lines together. `qbEvent.setPushType(QBPushType.GCM)` and `qbEvent.setPushType(QBPushType.APNS)`. Any solutions for that, please help?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to pass a push type param if you want to send a push to all platforms

**Solution N1 (only text):**

```
    QBEvent event = new QBEvent();
    event.setUserIds(userIds);
    event.setType(QBEventType.ONE_SHOT);
    event.setEnvironment(QBEnvironment.DEVELOPMENT);
    event.setNotificationType(QBNotificationType.PUSH);
    //
    event.setMessage("This is simple generic push notification!");
```

**Solution N2 (with custom parameters):**

```
    QBEvent event = new QBEvent();
    event.setUserIds(userIds);
    event.setType(QBEventType.ONE_SHOT);
    event.setEnvironment(QBEnvironment.DEVELOPMENT);
    event.setNotificationType(QBNotificationType.PUSH);
    //
    // generic push with custom parameters - http://quickblox.com/developers/Messages#Use_custom_parameters
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
      json.put("message", "This is generic push notification with custom params!");
      json.put("param1", "value1");
      json.put("ios_badge", "4"); // iOS badge value
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    event.setMessage(json.toString());
```

More examples in our push notifications snippets
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/master/snippets/src/main/java/com/sdk/snippets/modules/SnippetsPushNotifications.java#L217

and in documentation 
http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android#Universal_push_notifications